# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser how to get TR only from first table

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I have HTML code like following structure how in PHP to fetch TR only from first table using **PHP Simple HTML DOM find method**.

```
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="convertedTable">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td>...</td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
           </td>
          </tr>
<tr>
         <td>Some text</td>
          </tr>
<tr>...</tr>
....
         </tbody>
        </table>
```

I tried these conditions, but doesn't work.

`

```
$file->find('/body/table/tr')
$file->find('/body/table[!class]/tr')
$file->find('body table tr')
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: find first `tr` throught php? or css?

Comment: Could you share the code you've tried already?

Comment: FYI, SimpleHTMLDom is a terrible library

Comment: @l'L'l looked at the code? It's also not libxml based and has some nasty memory issues. The standard DOM extension has everything you need and is well written and documented. Here's a good resource for XML / HTML parsers ~ http://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/283366

Comment: @Phil, actually, no I haven't — always used the standard one; good to know though.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something as simple as this:

```
foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr) {
    // do something with $tr
    break; // stop now
}
```

Or specify it like this:

```
$tr = $html->find('tr', 0); // zero based index selector
```

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be able to do this easily with just a few lines:

```
$table = $html->find('table', 0);
foreach($table->find('table') as $tb) {
foreach($tb->find('tr') as $tr) {
        echo $tr;
    }
}
```

result:

```
<tr>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes, this work fine for only one TR in first TABLE, but if i have more TR in first TABLE, it doesn't work :-(

Comment: Now I try it, but it doesn't work. Processed all TR in first and nested table :-(

Comment: So you're trying to only get the `<tr>` items in the first table without any nested tables, correct? — I think that's what you mean. Anyway, it should work that way now.