# Get only the table rows from the first table - Simple HTML Dom (PHP)

Tags: php, html, html-table, simple-html-dom

```html
<table border="3" rules="all" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#000000">  <b>Maandag</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>Dinsdag</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>Woensdag</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>Donderdag</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>Vrijdag</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>1</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="18" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *verlof  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_4.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O114  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>2</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_3.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O114  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_7.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>3</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_1.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_1.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>4</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>5</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  stip  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  Os1  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_5.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V5B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V5C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_5.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V5B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V5C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>6</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_3.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_3.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>7</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_4.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_7.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_4.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_7.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>8</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_5.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V5B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V5C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_1.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>9</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My school supplies me with the following timetable (as seen above), but when I want to parse the table using simplehtmldom. From this table I want to collect the data so that I can use it in my App.

What query in simplehtmldom can i use to select only the first table rows?
Like this: Table->**(all rows)**

When I try this query: `echo($html->find('table tr',0));` And I change the the zero to 2 (for example), it doesn't return the next table row of the main table. But Instead it returns the frist table row of sub table in the first table row.

*Not that I can't change the way the table is presented, this is the table I have to work with.*

What I get now when I execute: `echo($html->find('table tr',2));` -> "Maandag"

What I would like to get: `<tr><td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1"><table><tbody><tr><td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>2</b>  </font> </td>  </tr></tbody></table></td>  <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1"><table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table></td>  <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1"><table><tbody><tr><td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_3.  </font> </td>  <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O114  </font> </td>  <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> </td>  </tr><tr><td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4C  </font> </td>  </tr></tbody></table></td>  <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1"><table><tbody><tr><td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_7.  </font> </td>  <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> </td>  <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> </td>  </tr><tr><td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4A  </font> </td>  </tr></tbody></table></td>  <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1"><table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>` **(the next tablerow of the first (main) table)**

The way I load in the html table:

```
$html = file_get_html($timetableURL);
$timeTable = $html->find('table',0); //I need to do this because the page with the timetable has more html tables, I tested this and it always fetches the timetable as seen above.
```

A related question: [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser how to get TR only from first table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616965/php-simple-html-dom-parser-how-to-get-tr-only-from-first-table)
Only I want to select the second or third row of the first table for example.

```
echo($timeTable->find('tr',2));
```

Comment: Can you show more of it like how your initializing DOM document and loading desired result into it. Then, it will be more easier for me.

Comment: Added it, I also added a related question, in which someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a while loop and the simple-html-dom nextSibling() function.

```
$tableCell = $row->find('td', 0);
while($tableCell){
   $tableCell = $tableCell->next_sibling(); //Go to the next tableCell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit convoluted with simple-html-dom:

```
// find the first table
$table = $html->find('table', 0);

// iterate all tr's
foreach($table->find('tr') as $tr){

  // skip the tr's that are not top level
  if($tr->parent->parent != $table) continue;

  do_something_with($tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery selector `:first` to fetch the first element from the DOM

You can do it like this:

```js
$(function() {
 var table = $('table:first');
 var table_rows = table.find('tr');
 alert(" There are " + table_rows.length + " rows in Table");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="3" rules="all" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#000000">  <b>Maandag</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>Dinsdag</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>Woensdag</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>Donderdag</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>Vrijdag</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>1</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="18" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *verlof  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_4.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O114  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>2</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_3.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O114  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_7.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>3</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_1.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_1.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>4</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>5</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  stip  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  Os1  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_5.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V5B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V5C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_5.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V5B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V5C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>6</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_3.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_3.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>7</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_4.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_7.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_4.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_7.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V4A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>8</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_5.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V5B  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V5C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  *in_1.  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  O112  </font> 
              </td>
              <td width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6A  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" width="33%" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  V6C  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="2" face="Arial">  <b>9</b>  </font> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That doesn't work as it also selects the nested table rows (tr). Also, I can't use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Traversing your DOM Structure, and I find that the `tr` that you want is the 4th child tr, which directly under a `tbody` element under the `table`.

So, the query you need might be something like this

```
// assume table is the root/parent DOM
$tr = $table->find('tbody > tr:nth-child(4)');
var_dump($tr->html());
```

Sorry if the php syntax is incorrect. That is actually tested against phpquery library.